# Which one is best to use Redux-thunk or redux-saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, redux-saga, mobx-react

I am very new to this redux.developed a project in flux now thought of upgrading it .I have used many API calls to get the data and used stores to get and retrieve data.
Can any one suggest me to use the right one either thunk or saga
In some blogs it was written to use MobX too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the choice between the two depends on the product requirements.  For simple UIs where there is simple data flow from a server response to react component, then just using thunk should suffice.  For more complicated async interactions (where there needs to be coordination between react components), sagas can help out quite a bit by providing structure to your code. There is some amount of learning curve with sagas so you might want to start very small and make sure you have plenty of test coverage for all your assumptions.  [Redux Saga Test Plan](https://redux-saga-test-plan.jeremyfairbank.com/) is great at helping you test your sagas.

For my current project, we started with thunk then transitioned to saga because our use cases were complex enough to leverage the benefit of sagas.

I have not used MobX so I can't comment on that.